# Visualizar la división con más departamentos (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo una duda muy tonta de bases de datos en SQL sobre una consulta, no logro dar con ella por más que intento...

Tengo dos tablas, DPTO (departamento) y PERSONAL.

Tabla DPTO:

[image: Tabla DPTO]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla PERSONAL

Y me pide visualizar la división que tiene más departamentos.

Pero no logro conseguir hacerlo, he probado de varias formas, pero acaba dándome distintos errores. Subconsulta, group, distinct...

Me he quedado aquí, y así llevo hora y pico buscando solución...

```
select DISTINCT d.Division
from DPTO D
INNER JOIN PERSONAL P ON D.NUMDPTO = P.DPTO
WHERE D.DIVISION >= ALL (select count(D.NUMDPTO) as NumDptos from DPTO)
```

Answer (score 1):

- Para encontrar el *mayor* valor, puedes ayudarte de una función de agregación como: `count()`
- Del mismo modo deberás agrupar por el resto de columnas que tengas en el *SELECT*
- Considero que no es necesario el *discriminar* valores por medio del uso de `DISTINCT`
- Para obtener la división con mayor cantidad de departamentos entonces ordenas de forma *descendente* por la columna generada por la función `count`
- Opcionalmente si solo quieres que la consulta te devuelva 1 registro entonces al final agregas un **LIMIT 1**

QUEDANDO DE ESTA FORMA:

```
SELECT DPTO.DIVISION,
       count(PERSONAL.DPTO) AS Maximo
FROM DPTO
INNER JOIN PERSONAL ON DPTO.NUMDPTO = PERSONAL.DPTO
GROUP BY DPTO.DIVISION
ORDER BY Maximo DESC;
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la aportación, volví a utilizar TOP 1, ya que antes parece que lo debí usar mal... y logré obtener el resultado, quedando así:

```select top 1 d.division, COUNT(d.numdpto) CantidadDptos
from DPTO D
INNER JOIN PERSONAL P ON P.DPTO = D.NUMDPTO
group by D.DIVISION```

Comment: Loren, si te ha servido la respuesta recuerda aceptarla y eventualmente darle un +1. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

WITH DATA_CTE
AS
(
SELECT
NUMDPTO, COUNT(PER.ID) AS CANTIDAD
FROM DPTO DEP
INNER JOIN PERSONAL PER ON(DEP.NUMDPTO = PER.DPTO)
),
DENSE_RANK_CTE
AS
(
SELECT
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CANTIDAD DESC) AS RANK
FROM DATA_CTE
)
SELECT * FROM DENSE_RANK_CTE WHERE RANK = 1

=JETAZAAAAA

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).